# Lock Active Directory accounts programmatically

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have to lock user accounts in Active Directory programmatically in C#.

Unfortunately it doesn't work via the userAccountControl attribute. Every time I set userAccountControl to 528 (=normal account w/ lockout flag), Active Directory won't accept the value and resets it without further notice to 512 (=normal account).

Now I tried to lock the account by providing incorrect credentials (see below), but this doesn't work either.

```
int retries = 0;
while (!adsUser.IsAccountLocked && retries < MAX_LOCK_RETRIES)
{
     retries++;

    try
    {  
        new DirectoryEntry(userPath, logonName, incorrectPassword).RefreshCache();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { 
        /* ... */ 
    }
    adsUser.GetInfo();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the account you're using to disable the account has sufficient privileges to disable accounts.  See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms696026(VS.85).aspx) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

This code will work to lock a user in AD

```
/// <summary>
/// Locks a user account
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userName">The name of the user whose account you want to unlock</param>
/// <remarks>
/// This actually trys to log the user in with a wrong password. 
/// This in turn will lock the user out
/// </remarks>
public void LockAccount(string userName)
{
    DirectoryEntry user = GetUser(userName);
    string path = user.Path;
    string badPassword = "SomeBadPassword";
    int maxLoginAttempts = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i &lt maxLoginAttempts; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            new DirectoryEntry(path, userName, badPassword).RefreshCache();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    user.Close();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had to implement the method `GetUser(userName)` myself though. I used a combination of `pc = PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)`, `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName)` and `.GetUnderlyingObject()` on the resulting object (cast to `DirectoryInfo`). Don't forget null-checks `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Active Directory policies, interactive login attempts may be required to lock an account.  You can simulate those using the [`LogonUser` method of advapi32.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  In my tests, I have seen that running this loop 100 times does not guarantee 100 bad password attempts at the domain controller, so you should [check the user is locked out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12992684/982237) and make more attempts if necessary.

The bottom line for this is that you should be disabling the account instead of trying to lock it.  There is [no functional difference between locked and disabled accounts](http://www.windows-active-directory.com/difference-between-disabled-expired-and-locked-account.html).  The code below is a hack.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            string userPrincipalName = "userID@domain.com";
            string authority = null; // Can be null when using UPN (user principal name)
            string badPassword = "bad";

            int maxTries = 100;
            bool res = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < maxTries; i++)
            {
                res = LogonUser(userPrincipalName, authority, badPassword, LogonSessionType.Interactive, LogonProvider.Default, out token);
                CloseHandle(token);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool LogonUser(
          string principal,
          string authority,
          string password,
          LogonSessionType logonType,
          LogonProvider logonProvider,
          out IntPtr token);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
        enum LogonSessionType : uint
        {
            Interactive = 2,
            Network,
            Batch,
            Service,
            NetworkCleartext = 8,
            NewCredentials
        }

        enum LogonProvider : uint
        {
            Default = 0, // default for platform (use this!)
            WinNT35,     // sends smoke signals to authority
            WinNT40,     // uses NTLM
            WinNT50      // negotiates Kerb or NTLM
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work once you have the directory entry object.

```
DirectoryEntry de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
int val = (int)de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | 0x0002;
```

Comment: This disables the account, this does not lock it.