# Check if Active Directory Account is Locked out (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory

Hello everyone (this is my first post)
I have some simple AD code that i pulled from Codeplex http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) and i am able to get all of our end user's information from said code. Now, I have been searching and searching and have found some interesting code snippets from here, and around the web regarding "Is the user locked out?"

I would like to use my code that I have been using for 2 years now, and just add a little bit more to it to add in the locked out part... I would be happy if there was a text box that gave me my info, or a check box, or something that just said "user locked" and then I would notify my Exchange team and have the user unlocked...

The code that I have is the following:

```
string eid = this.tbEID.Text;
string user = this.tbUserName.Text.ToString();
string path = "PP://dc=ds,dc=SorryCantTellYou,dc=com";

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path);

DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" + eid + "))";

SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();

//AD results
if (src.Count > 0)
{
   if (src[0].Properties.Contains("displayName"))
   {
      this.tbUserName.Text = src[0].Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();
   }
}
```

So, if I can figure out how to use the same directory entry, and searcher to show me the account lockout status that would be amazing.. please assist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1166393

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find the Locked property in Active Directory (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166263/cannot-find-the-locked-property-in-active-directory-c)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SamAccountName");

if(user != null)
{
    string displayName = user.DisplayName;

    if(user.IsAccountLockedOut())
    {       
        // do something here....    

    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: ok ok, i like that.... so if i already have the "username" or the SamAccountName (all that is is the EID that i have up there) how do i tie your code in with what i have up top?

Comment: @user1762132: just pass `eid` as your second parameter into `.FindByIdentity(ctx, eid)` and you should be done !

Comment: Ok, thats that i did.. so i dont have to punch in all that crazy OU and DC code anymore? This is what i have.. and please tell me if you think its cool... and thank you btw for answering the question :)

Comment: i wonder how i can run a quick query in my AD to find a locked out account so i can test this :) any ideas?

Comment: @user1762132: the `PrincipalContext` can still be creating in a specific domain and a specific (sub-)container inside that domain - with the *crazy* OU and DC codes :-) - but by default, it just picks up the current domain you're connected to and uses that.

Comment: hmm... so all of our users are in 5 different domains... will that matter when it comes time to find the "IsAccountLockedOut" ?

Comment: SO i have tested, and you are correct his works great.  How do i program that for the other 5 domains that we have?

Comment: @user1762132: use `PrincipalContext ctx1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN1");` and so on - you can define what domain to use for your context by using the overloaded constructors of `PrincipalContext`